# jQuery keeping an array, even when null value

Tags: jquery

I have created a script to add people to an ignore list, however once I've added them there is a problem with deleting them.
If I remove one user, from the array I can still add users to the ignore list. If I remove both people from the ignore list, I cannot add any more.
I have a feeling it's because "ignored_users" is no longer an array?

I add people to the ignore list using this code: {all vars are set, and works}

```
add_to_list = {
    "username" : username,
    "date_added" : "\"" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "\"", 
    "description" : desc
};
ignored_users.push(add_to_list);
localStorage["ignore_list"] = JSON.stringify(ignored_users);
```

The array starts looking like this:

```
ignored_users = [{"username":"test1","date_added":"\"4/7/2013\"","description":""},{"username":"test2","date_added":"\"4/7/2013\"","description":""}]
```

The remove from array code looks like this:

```
$.each(ignored_users, function(i, person) { 
    if(person.username === username)
    {
        delete ignored_users[i];
        localStorage["ignore_list"] = JSON.stringify(ignored_users);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you adding them?

Comment: add_to_list = {
     "username" : username,
     "date_added" : "\"" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "\"", 
     "description" : desc
    };
    ignored_users.push(add_to_list);
    localStorage["ignore_list"] = JSON.stringify(ignored_users);

Comment: why are you escaping those quote characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a native loop and `splice` instead. Removing an element from an array you are iterating over has caused issues for me when using `each` in the past. Try this:

```
ignored_users = [{
    "username": "test1",
    "date_added": "\"4/7/2013\"",
    "description": ""
}, {
    "username": "test2",
    "date_added": "\"4/7/2013\"",
    "description": ""
}]

var username = "test1";
for (var i = 0; i < ignored_users.length; i++) {
    if (ignored_users[i].username === username) {
        ignored_users.splice(i, 1);
        localStorage["ignore_list"] = JSON.stringify(ignored_users);
    }
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QJGu2/)

Comment: Perfect, I'll tick this when it allows me too! :D

Answer (score 0):

`delete ignored_users[i];` will not actually do what you want, it will make an element #i undefined, but will not shrink an array.

You need to use `splice()` method. To delete element #i from array:

```
array.splice(i, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `delete` to remove the element from the array, but this does not update the indexes of the array, it set to `undefined` the index you are deleting. So when you re-run your code again `person` will be undefined. Try with:

```
$.each(ignored_users, function(i, person) { 
    if(person && person.username === username)
    {
        delete ignored_users[i];
        localStorage["ignore_list"] = JSON.stringify(ignored_users);
    }
}
```

Also you can see other forms to delete an element from an array [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array).